# Run generated commands in same shell in order to access defined function

Tags: bash, function, scope, exec, subshell

In my Bash script, I'm generating a string which contains a series of commands. Some of these commands are references to a function defined within this script. That is:

```
function myfunc() {
...}
}

cmds=`echo "echo hello"; echo myfunc` # contrived, but you get the idea

bash $cmds
```

Now, running the commands by invoking a new Bash script doesn't work - the function `myfunc` isn't defined.

Is there a way around this? Either by making the function global somehow, or by making those commands run within the current shell?

Comment: The `` cmds=`echo foo` `` thing is highly suspicious. Don't execute stuff unless you actually need it, and use `$()` instead of backticks to avoid (some) quoting nightmares.

Comment: I tried to make clear that that's not the actual source of the commands - it's a `jq` script, fwiw.

Comment: [Don't use a string for commands.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) Use an array and then just expand it normally (unless you need redirections/brace expansion/etc. in which case you need more than that).

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise Bash had arrays. Not sure it really works in this situation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` in this case:

```
doit() { echo "ok"; }
foo="echo a; echo b; doit;"
eval "$foo"
```

Or output to a temporary script and source that.

Or you could use `export -f` to export the functions - that's bash-specific though (remember shellshock?).

Comment: Hmm, `eval` doesn't seem to work for a string containing newlines. (Maybe my script wasn't clear, but the variable contains multiple commands separated by newlines.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways: either use `export -f` to export the function, or use `eval` to execute the commands in the current shell.